how to use cert,key and cacert properties in springboot project
I have a cURL command which can connect to remote server. This command has attribute properties --cert --key and --cacert
curl -X POST "https://dppoapiproxy.linksfield.net/apiProxy/es2/confirmOrder" \
     --cert /home/useradmin/esim/esim.crt \
     --key /home/useradmin/esim/private.key \
     --cacert /home/useradmin/esim/lk-ca.crt \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
     "header":{
    "functionRequesterIdentifier":"4",
    "functionCallIdentifier":"TX-XXX-S"
    },
    "iccid":"89852071800485766278",
    "profileType":"",
    "eid":""
}'

how can I incorporate this cURL into a spring boot project and further use Resttemplate to connect to remote endpoint.
I mean what properties do I have to mention in application.properties file which can match to --cert , --key, --cacert used in this cURL command.
I am not asking for how to use resttemplate in sping boot. Rather I am asking what necessary properties/steps do I have to bind in order to connect to this remote server. Using cURL I am able to connect.

This question is similar to: Access Https Rest Service using Spring RestTemplate. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Oh wait, I just recalled - you can refer to these spring documentation https://spring.io/blog/2023/06/07/securing-spring-boot-applications-with-ssl i believe the spring ssl bundles should be what you are looking for not the server ssl properties which is used for securing the embedded web server.

where is "mybundle" mapped ? restTemplateBuilder.setSslBundle(sslBundles.getBundle("mybundle")).build();

That's covered in the blog post here https://spring.io/blog/2023/06/07/securing-spring-boot-applications-with-ssl#configuring-ssl-bundles and in the Spring Boot documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/reference/features/ssl.html
